# Fatal signal 11 when drawing a circle on a canvas with a bitmap shader

Tags: android

I am attempting draw a populate a gridview with circles of images i have stored on the phone. similar to 
[image]

But instead of having the solid / gradient colors i want to use images. Relevant code is

View which is drawn on

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_color_selected"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_colorpicker_swatch_selected"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Drawing on canvas

```
   @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(RaiseTheBarApplication.getInstance().getResources(), patternResource);
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(progressColor, 1));
        paint.setShader(shader);
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, RaiseTheBarApplication.getInstance().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.choose_color_radius), paint);
    }
```

choose_color_radius is 20dp

Gridview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rtb_dialog"
android:orientation="vertical">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gv_color_choice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:columnWidth="65dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"/>

<com.lvl.xpbar.views.baseviews.AFGTextView
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/button_submit"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_submit_background_selector"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

If i use Canvas#drawBitmap it works fine but I i use the logic above it I get

09-06 11:34:06.702  31659-31659/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x797ba000 (code=2), thread 31659 (com.lvl.xpbar)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: try to use software acceleration instead of the hw one (if any)

Comment: don't you have any warnings in onDraw method?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @greywolf82's I resolved this issue by disabling hardware acceleration for this view by using

setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);